# Is there a way to detect PHP version before getting parse error?

Tags: php

I have some problematic lines of codes with [array deferencing](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/functionarraydereferencing). Sometimes those lines causing problems if the hosting has PHP 5.3 or below.

Is there a way to detect PHP version and give a proper warning before having this kind of error :

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '[' in

Comment: Not from within the same script – because it is a parse error that occurs before your script is even run.

Comment: if (version_compare(phpversion(), '5.3.10', '<')) {
            //Write code.
        }

Comment: no this is not possible on same page.

Answer (score 0):

got it from [this](http://php.net/manual/en/function.phpversion.php) :

```
echo 'Current PHP version: ' . phpversion();
```

But only from another page. May be you should use kind of internal redirect.

Answer (score 0):

If you have some single-entry bootstrap file, you can put something like this there:

```
if (PHP_VERSION_ID < 50300) {
    die('PHP 5.3 or higher is required');
}
```

See http://php.net/phpversion for a lot of further tips and tricks.

Consider that this check needs to run on every single page load; while it's not very expensive, it's still *one more thing* that needs to be done. Simply clearly documenting your version requirements or doing this check once in a setup script or such may be more sensible.

Also consider that this check needs to be done in a file which is fully compatible with PHP <5.3; if in the same file that parse error is raised, it won't be able to execute this check either.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [version_compare](http://php.net/manual/en/function.version-compare.php) for this.

For example (from the docs):

```
if (version_compare(PHP_VERSION, '5.3.0') >= 0) {
    echo 'I am at least PHP version 5.3.0, my version: ' . PHP_VERSION . "\n";
}
```